# AND statement in SQL confusing me

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to work out exactly what an SQL query is doing by breaking it down. The query looks like this:

```
select count(*) as totalvaluecount,  value as thevalue, DATE(date_created) as thedate
            FROM cb_lead INNER JOIN cb_lead_detail ON cb_lead.id = cb_lead_detail.lead_id
            WHERE cb_lead.form_id = '$form_id' AND date_created BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)
            AND NOW() AND field_number = '23' GROUP BY thevalue, thedate
```

The line `AND field_number = '23'` is confusing me. What does this clause do? Is it saying ‘if the field_number is 23’?

Also, where is it looking for `field_number`? Is it in `cb_lead` or `cd_lead_detail`?

Comment: is your query running or giving error

Comment: Since the confusion came from the poor formatting, I'm not sure that tidying it is a good idea, @Kritner. Generally, I'd leave code in questions alone.

Comment: @TRiG at the time of my updating the formatting I wasn't sure that that *was* the confusion in the question.  Otherwise I would have just done it in my answer as you did.  Feel free to roll it back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would format that query slightly differently, which would (I think) make it easier to read:

```
SELECT
        COUNT(*) AS totalvaluecount,
        value AS thevalue,
        DATE(date_created) AS thedate
FROM
        cb_lead
INNER JOIN
        cb_lead_detail
        ON cb_lead.id = cb_lead_detail.lead_id
WHERE
        cb_lead.form_id = '$form_id'
        AND date_created BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY) AND NOW()
        AND field_number = '23'
GROUP BY
        thevalue,
        thedate
```

The part you’re asking about is `AND field_number = '23'`. Yes, this is part of the `WHERE` clause, so as you surmised, it is restricting the result set to records where the `field_number` column has the value of `23`.

The query is on two tables joined. In that situation, it is usual to represent the column as `table_name.field_name`, but this is not actually necessary so long as the field name is unique to one table. So there’s no way of knowing which table this column (or the other columns mentioned without a table name prefix) are in just from studying this query. It would, of course, be easy to discern from a glance at the database structure.

Comment: Thanks for that, reformatting the query makes it much easier to understand

Comment: @fightstarr20 . . . Interesting.  I don't see that this version is any easier or harder to understand than the version in your question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff. Try viewing the edit history on the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yeah, that's my bad.  I had applied some formatting to the OPs original query as it was hard to parse, but it turns out that was the OPs actual confusion (the original formatting of the query I mean).

Comment: I've popped it back now, @Kritner. No harm.

Comment: The line wrap on the `BETWEEN` clause is particularly confusing, I think, @GordonLinoff.

Comment: @Trig . . . The history makes a big difference.  Not my preferred indenting style, but clearly better than what the OP originally wrote.

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE cb_lead.form_id = '$form_id'
```

Get only forms with a form_id of $form_id

```
    AND date_created BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY) AND NOW()
```

and records where the date created is between 14 days ago and now

```
    AND field_number = '23'
```

and the field_number is 23

> Is it saying 'if the field_number is 23'?

that is indeed what it is saying.

> Also, where is it looking for field_number? Is it cb_lead or cd_lead_detail?

that depends on which table has that particular column.  If *both* of the tables have that column then this query would fail to execute with an "ambiguous column error" or similar.  If the query executes successfully, then the column only exists on one of the two tables in your query... but since you didn't provide your schema of the two tables, it's impossible to say which table it's in from our point of view.  It should be easy enough for you to confirm however.